# When there is a noun phrase with "or" with 1 singular noun and 1 plural noun, should the verb be singular or plural? Example: "UPS or others"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Example Sentence:

> Can Amazon stock go down if the UPS or other Amazon shipping partners suddenly **jack** up their shipping prices?

Is it plural, *jack*, or singular, *jacks*? Usually with two singular nouns combined by or, I'm pretty sure it's a singular verb like *The book or pen **is** in the drawer*. But how about two nouns, one singular and one plural, combined by *or*?

Comment: The general rule is that the closest noun rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conjunction "or" and the plural rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321064/conjunction-or-and-the-plural-rule) (which I'm sure is not the earliest nor the best duplicate).